# Chrome console + text editor

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I find myself typing JavaScript in the console a lot. For example, I quickly want to see the result if I change the property of a certain object. However every time that I refresh the page I have to redefine my variables, etc. I do this by using the up-key, so I do not have to retype, but this costs a lot of time. What is a better way?

The ultimate coolness would be an environment like [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) in which you can write multi line code and from there execute it directly in the browser... And then still have the autocomplete list of all the methods of an object (like in the console). Obviously this is not available, but I am very interesting in the workflow of other when typing JavaScript code in the console.

Comment: Do you Shift+Enter make a new line without submitting your code?

Comment: Yeah sometimes but I don't like it to much. Because I somehow cannot work as fast as I would like to.

Answer (score 14):

In Chrome 24's `Sources` panel, use the `Snippets` tab. Right-click in the left (blank) tree and choose `New` from the context menu.

Comment: This is a nice feature. You don't have the object methods completion within the "snippet panel" though. Therefor you still have to use the console. But it is definitely useful. Thanks.